# Multivalue in DXA 1.5

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-1.5

I am working on DXA 1.5 and trying to bind multiple value(Keywords) in model but not sure on how to move forward on this. i tried following types `List<string>` `Tag` and  `List<Tag>`to get the multiple values but no luck. Though I am able to get single keyword value using type of string.

Please suggest on the same. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

You should get your multi value Taxonomy binded in your model by using `List<Tag>`. Your field in model should be like:

```
[SemanticProperty("keywordField")]
public List<Tag> KeywordField{ get; set; }
```

If you want to extend default model binder behavior you can see my answer in [this](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15201/issue-with-dxa-defaultmodelbinder-for-keyword-field) question. If you are still facing any issue, I can suggest just try to debug the issue in DXA code.